# for() statement instructions order

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

I would like to make sure I understand for() loop in java. From java tutorials:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

Docs says: "The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop"

```
int x = 10;
for(int y=2;x!=1;x++){
    System.out.print(x);
    x=x-y;
    //actual x++ operation?
}
//prints 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
```

is `x` incremented after `System.out` and `x=x-y`?

Comment: there is this thing debugger you can use ...you know

Answer (score 4):

This block

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    initialization;
    for (; termination; ) {
        statement(s)
        increment;
    }
}
```

Note the extra scoping braces in the second equivalent. This emphasises that a variable declared in the initialisation step is out of scope after the final `}`.

So your comment `//actual x++ operation?` **is** in the correct place: immediately before your closing brace.

Comment: I always felt it was easiest explaining this using a while loop to express the flow of execution; although this works too

Answer (score 3):

Yes. X is incremented after the complete operation is run. So even if you do things to x, it should increment regardless.. So in each step you subtract one from x because you start by subtracting two, then add one from the increment.